Unable to match function definition when type in concept template is aliased
I think i found a bug in MSVC, but i wanted to confirm. I have the following simple reproducer:
template <typename T, typename R>
concept convertible_range =
    std::ranges::sized_range<R> && std::convertible_to<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>, T>;

template <typename T>
struct S {
    using value_type = T;
    template <convertible_range<value_type> R>
    void foo(R&&);
};

template <typename T>
template <convertible_range<T> R>
void S<T>::foo(R&&) {}

This compiles with gcc-14.1 but fails in all versions of MSVC++ with:

error C2244: 'S::foo': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Live example
The issue appears to be a combination of defining foo outside the class using the type alias in the declaration of foo in S. If i either:

define the function in place:

struct S {
    using value_type = T;
    template <convertible_range<value_type> R>
    void foo(R&&) {}
};


Change the declaration to use T directly:

template <typename T>
struct S {
    template <convertible_range<T> R> // Difference is here!
    void foo(R&&);
};

template <typename T>
template <convertible_range<T> R>
void S<T>::foo(R&&) {}

Then this compiles.
Is this an MSVC bug?
